# Selenium how to convert the String data of 'say' 2000.0 to convert to 2000 and remove the floating point and trailing zeros

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using `Selenium WebDriver` (Java) and passing the `String` value that has decimal point and leading zero. I want to remove it. This is what I'm trying but doesn't work:

```
String data=2000.0
Long.parseLong(data);
```

Comment: Parse it to a `Double` and then cast it to a `Long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(long)Double.parseDouble("2000.0");
```

It first converts the String to double and then converts it to long.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    String data = "2000.0";
    int i = (int)Double.parseDouble(data);
```

Comment: change `s` to `data` I try to edit but i got `Edits must be at least 6 characters`

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement this -

```
String data = "2000.0";
int i = Integer.parseInt(data);
```